# Nodejs how to raw html

Tags: node.js, pug

In my Nodejs app,my router is:

```
app.get('/admin/test',function(req,res){
  res.render('./admin/test.jade',{html:'<h1>hello world</h1>'});
})
```

view `test.jade` is :

```
div=html
```

The result is that I just see:

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

Not a `h1` element.

So what should I do to show the raw html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `!{}` to give the output parses the HTML:

```
div
   !{html}
```